# How to fix XCode invivisble Headers and Clang compiler issue in MacOS?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, llvm-clang

GCC- Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29) is giving me weird results when I try to run any C++/C program. For example, running this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string hello = "Hello world";
    std::cout << hello << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run with gcc or g++

```
gcc template.cpp -o template
```

It gives me this error

```
In file included from template.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:624:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/initializer_list:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstddef:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stddef.h:50:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__nullptr:23:29: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS'
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS nullptr_t
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__nullptr:23:8: note: forward declaration of 'std::__1::_LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS'
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS nullptr_t
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__nullptr:23:38: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS nullptr_t
                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__nullptr:46:52: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR nullptr_t __get_nullptr_t() {return nullptr_t(0);}
                                                   ^
In file included from template.cpp:2:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/istream:163:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:140:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/locale:192:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:167:44: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long      abs(     long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return  labs(__x);}
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:110:44: note: target of using declaration
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long      abs(     long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return  labs(__x);}
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:135:9: note: using declaration
using ::abs;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:169:44: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long long abs(long long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return llabs(__x);}
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:112:44: note: target of using declaration
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long long abs(long long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return llabs(__x);}
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:135:9: note: using declaration
using ::abs;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:172:42: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY  ldiv_t div(     long __x,      long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return  ldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:115:42: note: target of using declaration
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY  ldiv_t div(     long __x,      long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return  ldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:143:9: note: using declaration
using ::div;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:174:42: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY lldiv_t div(long long __x, long long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return lldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:117:42: note: target of using declaration
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY lldiv_t div(long long __x, long long __y) _NOEXCEPT {return lldiv(__x, __y);}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:143:9: note: using declaration
using ::div;
        ^
7 errors generated.
```

I think I caused this when I was trying to copy some library header files to **`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`**

Now I am unable to compile any C++ program on my Mac. I can't understand how to fix this.

I tried installing llvm and adding it's path but nothing helps.

```
> brew install llvm   
==> Installing dependencies for llvm: libffi
==> Installing llvm dependency: libffi
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libffi-3.3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libffi-3.3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
libffi is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libffi/include"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3: 16 files, 489.4KB
==> Installing llvm
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/llvm-10.0.0_3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/ea/ea9b9f579df49499d9ab0084e10edecc5350298d6c5db399a1dabc8694dab7db?__gda__=exp=1587779777~hmac=fa0024a2581a685070cc1612da34abc29c53c8c352dce2f47c74d841c
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring llvm-10.0.0_3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3: 7,055 files, 1GB

> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
~
```

Current versions of installed Clang:

```
> gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> g++ version
```

Comment: I also tried one solution from some other question to run but it gives me an error saying header files not found.

`> clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++ -I/.../llvm-project/libcxx/include -L/.../llvm-project/libcxx/lib -Wl,-rpath,/.../llvm-project/libcxx/lib selection_sort.cpp -o selection
selection_sort.cpp:3:9: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
`#include<iostream>
        ^~~~~~~~~~`
`1 error generated.`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution. Earlier I was using XCode Application and I messed up some library files when I was trying to copy header files to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`

It turned so fatal that I was totally helpless. Neither my C++ or C code would compile, nor Node Applications would build due to `gyp`.

Apparently it some more errors, when I tried to reinstall few things and my homebrew gave a page full of errors with unbrewed header files.

**Solution:**

I removed Xcode Application, switched to Command line tool.
Removed llvm, and it worked.

You need to switch the XCode path, you do it by:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

You are good to go, and never mess up with the files inside SDK, else it will cost you hours of panic. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had to re-install the `xcode tools` for some weird reason...

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Yeah Biswa, that works. But still doesn't solve the problem. 
And by the way, I did mention this in solutions. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues building a meteor app that had a `node-gyp` dependency, in the end I was able to follow the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666700) to get the build to work

Specifically exporting this flag:

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
```

The failure looked like

```
> bufferutil@4.0.4 install /Users/ben.ritchie/Documents/dev/connect4/connect4mvp/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp-build

  CC(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.c:2:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:42:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.c:3:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node_api.h:12:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api.h:24:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api_types.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/stdint.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.c:3:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node_api.h:12:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api.h:24:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api_types.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/stdint.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean 'uint64_t'?
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types/_uint64_t.h:31:28: note: 'uint64_t' declared here
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
                           ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.c:3:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node_api.h:12:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api.h:24:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api_types.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/stdint.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.c:3:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node_api.h:12:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api.h:24:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api_types.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/stdint.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:53:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.c:3:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node_api.h:12:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api.h:24:
In file included from /Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/js_native_api_types.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/stdint.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:53:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:32:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'
typedef __darwin_intptr_t       intptr_t;
        ^
18 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.5.0.sgqk5k.nggn++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1fm8up2.pjm8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/Users/ben.ritchie/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.5.0.sgqk5k.nggn++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ben.ritchie/Documents/dev/connect4/connect4mvp/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v12.20.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
```